# Convert month name to month number in a date, two digits day and month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  a date given as

```
'2015-DEC-01'
```

which I want to convert to

```
'2015-12-01'
```

Please notice that I want two digits for the month and day, that is essential for me. Here is my attempt:
`select CONCAT(datepart(yyyy,'2015-DEC-01'),'-',datepart(mm,'2015-DEC-01'),'-',datepart(dd,'2015-DEC-01'))`

It gives the answer as:
`2015-12-1`
As we can see I am looking for two digits for month as well as day i.e.
I need 01 in place of 1
Can I get some assistance here? thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cast()` or `convert()`:

```
select cast('2015-DEC-01' as date)
```

`cast()` with strings to dates is much more flexible than one would first imagine.  It works in this case.

This converts the value to a date.  You can then format it however you like using `format()` or `convert()`.  For instance:

```
select convert(varchar(10), cast('2015-DEC-01' as date), 121)
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Comment: I prefer to use `CONVERT` and I've probably worn out the bookmark to the MSDN cast/convert page and all of the available options